# Howto get_env(REQUEST_METHOD) w/o ERROR 500

Tags: html, c, gdb, cgi

I'm working on a CGI file using C that does things only if the request method is POST.

```
int main(void)
{
    char    *method_str = getenv("REQUEST_METHOD");
    int iMethod = strcmp(method_str,"POST");
    int tid = 0;
    int own_id = 0;
    char    key[16] = "\0";


    if (iMethod == -1) {
        puts("Location:start.cgi\n\n");
    } else if (iMethod == 0) {
        char    *data = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
        int size = atoi(data);
        char    *buffer = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(char));
        fgets(buffer,atoi(data)+1,stdin);
        int counter = count(buffer);
        char    **names = malloc(counter*sizeof(char *));
        char    **values = malloc(counter*sizeof(char *));
        parse(buffer, names, values);
        int isDel = strcmp(*(values+1),"Back to Start");
        if (isDel == 0) startpage(atoi(*values));
        else {
            own_id = atoi(*values);
            sprintf(key,"%s",*(values+1));
            int stat = login_status(own_id,key);
            if (stat == -1) {
                startpage(0);
            } else userpage(own_id);
        }
        free_mallocs(names,values,counter);
        free(buffer);

    }
    free(method_str);

    return 0;
}
```

Running the CGI file in gdb tells me that the problem is in the line:

> `int  iMethod = strcmp(method_str,"POST");`. The error is SIGSEGV.

The CGI runs fine when I open it from a XAMPP server. However, when I run it in an Ubuntu server different from mine, Error 500 occurs. I tried comparing the value of `getenv("REQUEST_METHOD")` with NULL, and gdb tells me that the file ran normally. However, the CGI file failed to run properly on both my XAMPP server and the other server, with the two showing error 500. 
What I can tell you is that the functions have their Content headers set. The functions count() and parse() were set appropriately and independent of the situation at hand.
Thanks in advance.

Update: If the user opens the CGI file directly, the browser will redirect to another CGI file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcmp` will segfault when the first parameter is `NULL`. Check for `NULL` and you'd be fine:

```
char *method_str = getenv("REQUEST_METHOD");
int iMethod = -1;
if (method_str != NULL) 
     iMethod = strcmp(method_str,"POST");
}
```

As an extra, try to avoid `strcmp` and always use `strncmp` as it is safer:

```
strncmp(method_str, "POST", 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure what *exactly* you are asking but [`getenv()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv) returns `NULL` if the environment variable does not exist. Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is undefined behaviour and the pointer passed to `strcmp()` will be dereferenced. Passing `NULL` as an argument to `strcmp()` is the therefore undefined behaviour, which can be a segmentation fault (and is the probable cause here). Protect the call to `strcmp()` with a `NULL` check on `method_str`.

Why the environment variable does not exist I do not know.

Comment: I also noticed the NULL value of the `getenv()` when I run the file on gdb. The reason why I used `strcmp()` is because when I run the script on my XAMPP server, the default value of `getenv("REQUEST_METHOD")` is "GET". I also do not know why the env variable does not exist. The next thing I did was I removed the pointer to char, compared the `getenv("REQUEST_METHOD")` directly to the string "POST", and analysed the return values. Still, there's error 500. I will try to fix the code.